# no logro que al mover el control deslizante se actualice solo el resultado, Tkinter Scale

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, scale

Cordial saludo amigos, tengo el siguiente código:

```
from tkinter import *

def suma():

    valor2 = 0
    R = valor2 + valor1.get()
    return resultado.set(R)

root = Tk()
root.title("Slider - Funcionamiento")
root.geometry('1000x600+120+40')
root.iconbitmap('descarga.ico')
root.resizable(0,0)

valor1 = IntVar()
resultado = IntVar()
Slider1 = Scale(root, orient = VERTICAL, length = 155, from_ = 0, to = 10, 
            tickinterval = 1, variable = valor1)
Slider1.place(x = 200, y = 200)

pantalla = Entry(root, textvariable = resultado, state = "disable")
pantalla.place(x = 32, y = 500)
boton10 = Button(root, text = "suma", width = 20, height = 1, 
            command = suma)
boton10.place(x = 130, y = 360)

root.mainloop()
```

lo que quisiera es que al mover el scale, y variar entre sus valores, el resultado que se muestra en el Entry cambie sin necesidad de estar presionando el boton de resultado.

¿como puedo lograr esto? Agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: añade `command=lambda *args: suma()` en la creación del Scale.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfectamente.